Get relevant script for (all) mappings
vim.api.nvim_get_keymap('n') does return a table with lnum (line number) , but not with the name of the script that set it (or path). I only know that verbose nmap .. does it, but prefer to avoid it (as needs to be called separately for each).
Any way in lua to obtain this?

Can you use maplist() or maparg() from Vim's API?

Ah,yes. I am on nvim, so no maplist (guess it is because of it). maparg has the same issue.

I think the simplest call might be :verbose nmap without specific mapping which I can run as it doesn't need to be called separately for each mapping.
